# Unable to find System types when building Xamarin iOS project

Tags: ios, xamarin

I'm building a multi-platform class library with Xamarin. The Android project builds with no problem. But the iOS project gives me a bunch of errors like this, for various `System` types:

`error CS0012: The type 'System.IDisposable' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'`

This happens regardless of whether I build via Visual Studio, or on the command line with `msbuild`.

My .csproj has these framework references and package references:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="System" />
  <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  <Reference Include="System.Core" />
  <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
  <Reference Include="Xamarin.iOS" />
  <PackageReference Include="Common.Logging" Version="3.4.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.Essentials" Version="0.8.0-preview" />
  <PackageReference Include="Xam.Plugin.DeviceInfo" Version="4.0.0.13" />
  <PackageReference Include="My.Other.Library" Version="1.0.2" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Note that `My.Other.Library` is not an iOS project; it has targets of `netstandard1.4`, `netstandard1.6`, `netstandard2.0`, and `net45`. I'm guessing that that is not the problem, because the same library is also used by my Android project, which works fine.

Currently these two projects have the same code - that is, they both compile the same `.cs` files from a shared directory, except for `AssemblyInfo.cs` which exists separately in each project. They also have the same assembly references, except that the Android project uses `Mono.Android` rather than `Xamarin.iOS`.

I'm using Mac Visual Studio Community 7.5.2.

Any ideas?