# Build multi-platform Xamarin class library - single project or multiple projects?

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, multiplatform

I'm trying to build a class library that includes some platform-specific stuff, i.e. there will be multiple targets including iOS and Android in one package.

As I understand it, there are basically two ways to go:

1. A single `.csproj` file with multiple TargetFrameworks. There is a Xamarin example using this approach in the article ["Multi-targeting the world: a single project to rule them all"](https://oren.codes/2017/01/04/multi-targeting-the-world-a-single-project-to-rule-them-all/). I think it is probably out of date-- when I try to build according to that example, I get errors about the various `Targets` files not existing at the right path. But I at least understand the basic idea.
2. Multiple `.csproj` files, one for each target framework, with a `.nuproj` file to gather them together into a package, as described [in these Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/nuget-multiplatform-libraries/platform-specific). I've managed to set up a project like this and *almost* get it to build, although I'm still having [a few problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51529609/unable-to-find-system-types-when-building-xamarin-ios-project).

I'm just wondering if one approach has clear advantages versus the other, and if there are any better examples of a solution like this that I've overlooked.